# Ordering in sitecore template fields

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a structure in my sitecore content tree

- Content Type A (Class 1)

  - Content Type B (Jane)
  - Content Type B (Alex)
  - Content Type B (Liam)
- Content Type A (Class 2)

  - Content Type B (Bob)
- Content Type A (Class 3)
- ....

I then display all Content Type B in a Checkbox List as the source for a field in another template (essentially picking related content) this works but I now need to display it in alphabetical order regardless of which Content type A content it is under ie display

- Alex
- Bob
- Jane
- Liam

rather than

- Alex
- Jane
- Liam
- Bob

I can't see any mention of syntax in the sitecore query that supports that type of ordering. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you get the list of Sitecore items through .NET you should also be able to do something like `YourListOfItems.OrderBy(i => i.Name)`.

You can get the list of items by using `Sitecore.ContentSearch` in Sitecore 7 and up, or your Sitecore query as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks, the issue here is that I need the items for a list tpe Sitecore template field that a content editor would populate within Sitecore itself (rather than in front end). I can't think how I could use .NET to do this without customizing the Checkbox list control which seems like should be overkill.

Comment: I see. I don't think Sitecore query supports any ordering, but what you might be able to do is set the 'Sort Order' field in the editor. I'm not 100% sure if this will work as I haven't tried it before. You could then, on creation of an item of Content Type B, have a bit of code that runs and sets the sort order field to the correct item. 

Having said that, I think it'd be easiest (from maintenance point of view) to create a custom Checkbox control.

Answer (score 0):

try this option,

In the standard value of your "Content Type B" Template

puts this value: $name  in your "Sort" Field

so, now your items should be sorted by name.
and logically all values should be sorted in your checkboxList

Answer (score 0):

You can use .net method to do this

var newList = people.OrderBy(x=>x.NameCategory).ToList();